# Disconnect subprocess from main process

Tags: linux, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a Python 3 script which, among other things, launches Chrome with certain command-line parameters. The relevant portion of the code looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from subprocess import call
import time
import logging

def launch_tab(datadir, url):
    # Constructs the command line and launches Chrome via subprocess.call()

def open_browser(urls):
    '''Arranges for Chrome to be launched in a subprocess with the specified
    URLs, using the already-configured profile directory.

    urls: a list of URLs to be loaded one at a time.'''
    first_run = True
    for tab in urls:
        logging.debug('open_browser: {}'.format(tab))
        proc = mp.Process(name=tab, target=launch_tab, args=(config.chromedir, tab))
        proc.start()
        if first_run:
            first_run = False
            time.sleep(10)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

### What Happens

- When I run the script with Chrome already running as launched by the script:

  1. Chrome launches as expected, sees that it is already running, follows the instructions provided on the command line, then terminates the process started on the command line.
  2. Since the process is now terminated, my script also terminates. This is the behavior I want.
- When I run the script while Chrome is not running:

  1. Chrome sees that it is not already running, and so doesn't terminate the process started by the command line.
  2. Because the process hasn't terminated, my script doesn't exit until Chrome does, despite its having nothing to do. I have to remember to place the script in the background.

### What I Want

I want the subprocess which launches Chrome to be completely independent of the main process, such that I get my command prompt back immediately after Chrome is launched. After launching Chrome, my script has completed its job. I thought of using the `daemonize` module, but it apparently doesn't work with Python 3.

I'm not wedded to the `multiprocessing` module. Any reasonable approach which produces the desired end result is acceptable. Switching to Python 2 so I can try `daemonize` would be too difficult.

The script will only ever run on Linux, so portability isn't an issue.